# Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку менялся фон с 1 видео на другое

Tags: javascript, html, css, видео

Мне хочется чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, фон(1 видео) менялся на 2 видео. Как это сделать на языке js?

*Пробовал разные варианты - не получается. Не один не работает. Js кода нету, но html и css есть. Кнопку можете любую, я потом ее легко поменяю. Если дадите хотя бы сырой код который это сможет сделать, я буду очень благодарен*

Второе видео называется Fon_2.mp4

html

```
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
    <source src="../mp4/Fon_1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

css

```
#myVideo {
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: -1000;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: `button.onclick=()=>{document.getElementById("myVideo").children[0].src="../mp4/Fon_2.mp4");}`

Comment: Вставь в html `<button onclick='document.querySelector("source").src = "../mp4/Fon_2.mp4"'>`

Comment: странно, в коде Васи отображает красные ошибки (конец кода), а руди - обводит source желтым цветом. Почему так сложно все